# Rails 3 x_sendfile on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3 allow to send static files directly and more performantly to HTTP clients and bypassing your app server process (as described see [http://john.guen.in...](http://john.guen.in/past/2007/4/17/send_files_faster_with_xsendfile/))

```
send_file '/path/to.png', :x_sendfile => true, :type => 'image/png'
```

I want to deploy my app on [heroku](http://www.heroku.com).

heroku use Nginx 0.6.32 (see http://docs.heroku.com/aspen).

Does `x_sendfile` works on heroku?

Here is what i found on Nginx http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxXSendfile

Cheers

Comment: hi did you have any luck with this?  I am going to try it out today as I have some large files that I need to serve and really don't want my rails processes tied up too much

Comment: no I don't, i'm interested if you make it works

Comment: do you store these files with your app in git? I recommend using amazon S3 for this. It's an http link and will be served directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

X-Sendfile doesn't work on Heroku.  More details are available in this thread from the Heroku Google group: [What is rails3_disable_x_sendfile?](http://groups.google.com/group/heroku/browse_thread/thread/c6bef57980c5828e/a6c50309e924dbb4)